# Connector/python executemany NoneType

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I have a little problem with Connector/python executing insert query.

I have function to insert data into database. Argument data is list of tuples:
[(2652884, 'http://www.example.com/', '5.0.5.239', 1), ..... ]

```
def insert_url(self, data):

    query = "INSERT INTO `sp_urls` (`parent_id`, `url`, `version`, `hits`) VALUES (%d, %s, %s, %d) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE url=url"        


    try:
        cursor = self.__cnx.cursor()
        cursor.executemany(query, data)
    except (mysql.connector.errors.IntegrityError) as err:
        print("Query syntax error:", err, file=sys.stderr)
    except (mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) as err:
        print("Programming err:{0}".format(err))
    finally:
        cursor.close()
```

The query itself works, in self.__cnx is initialized connection.
Here's the traceback:

```
  File "sdi/database/DbValidator.py", line 91, in process_records
    self.__driver.insert_url(urldata)
  File "/home/david/workspace/stickydi/sdi/database/MySQLDriver.py", line 87, in insert_url
    cursor.executemany(query, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 492, in executemany
    return self._batch_insert(operation,seq_params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 428, in _batch_insert
    fmt = m.group(1).encode(self._connection.charset)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

I have one very similar method, and it works OK, I just can't see, why does  executemany( )  goes wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should *not* use `%d` for SQL parameters. Stick to `%s` and let the MySQL connector handle the types:

```
query = """\
    INSERT INTO `sp_urls` (`parent_id`, `url`, `version`, `hits`) 
    VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE url=url
    """
```

Quoting from the [Python-MySQL documentation](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html):

> `paramstyle`
>   String constant stating the type of parameter marker formatting expected by the interface. Set to `'format'` = ANSI C `printf` format codes, e.g. `'...WHERE name=%s'`. If a mapping object is used for conn.execute(), then the interface actually uses `'pyformat'` = Python extended format codes, e.g. `'...WHERE name=%(name)s'`. However, the API does not presently allow the specification of more than one style in paramstyle.

Granted, using `%s` for SQL parameters is confusingly similar to Python string formatting, but it is not the same.

Comment: I read about the formatting convention very briefly a while ago and I remembred only that it's C-like convention, so I thought it works with %d, too. I was obviously wrong, thank you for explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Use only `%s` as the parameter marker in `query`. Do not use `%d`:

```
query = """
    INSERT INTO `sp_urls` (`parent_id`, `url`, `version`, `hits`) 
    VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE url=url"""
```

The `%s` is the `format` [paramstyle defined in the DB-API](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle). It does not have the same meaning as `%s` in string formatting.

The correct paramstyle to use depends on the database driver. MySQLdb  uses `%s`. Other database drivers such as [oursql](http://pythonhosted.org/oursql/) and [sqlite3](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) use `?`.